# html5 canvas units

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been playing around with the html5 canvas and don't understand how the units work. I saw on MDN that one "unit" on the canvas should be 1 pixel. So I drew a canvas 800px wide x 400px high. Then I drew a rectangle at the coordinate 400, 200 which I thought would put the top left corner dead center. However, it got put far off the screen. When I scaled it back to about 200, 100 or so I could see the rectangle but it didn't logically make any sense where it ended up.

Long story short. How does the coordinate system in canvas work?

Comment: Did you set the width and height with CSS or with the HTML `width` and `height` attributes?

Comment: Please post the code, and possibly do a http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Note that 1 canvas unit is 1 pixel if the canvas logical dimensions are set to the same as the display dimensions AND you have not performed any scaling on your context; in general, however, a canvas may rasterize your 'pixels' sizes to some other size in its bitmap, and then the browser may choose to draw that bitmap at some other size.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That should be correct. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hvyvY/

Please note that you must use the width and height attributes of the HTMLCanvasElement to set its size, like:

`<canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="400">`

NOT the CSS style of that element. Changing the CSS style of the Canvas will scale it instead.

Comment: Thanks!  So counter intuitive when you're used to using CSS to control width and height.  Cost me hours but you sorted it for me.